# Data Cleansing: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I have some dirty data that I would like to cleanse by converting the incorrect values to the mean. I currently have the following code;

```
def convert_bad_data(x):
    if x < 16:
        x == np.mean
        return x
    elif x > 80:
        x == np.mean
        return x
    else:
        return x
```

When I run this I get the following error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

The thing is I am not looking to use a boolean so am not sure why I am getting an error about a truth value.

Comment: @ayhan Hi, This question has a similar title but they questions are not exactly related. I don't use `and` `or` in my code.

Comment: From the duplicate: "What you hit was a place where the operator implicitly converted the operands to bool (you used  `or` but it also happens for `and`, `if` and `while`)" They are basically the same. You cannot do `some_series and some_other_series` and you also cannot do `if some_series`.

Comment: ˋdef issue_ago(date):
    today = datetime.today()
    if type(date) == str:
        date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
        #print date
        epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1)
        diff = today - date
        date = diff.days /365.25
        return date
    else:
        return dateˋ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `x` you're passing is a series, so asking if `x < 16` is ambiguous.  Instead, you should be using `any()` if want the condition to trigger if *any* elements of x are < 16, or `all()` if you want them *all* to be.

Comment: I thought I would be iterating through the values in my dataset with each value from each row being set to x each time.

Comment: @Taylrl If you want to do that, you'll need to add an explicit loop over the values before your if/else statements.

Comment: I have written functions before that iterate over a dataset but yet dont need a loop. I am missing something here.